# nodejs fetch response coming in console but not assigning to a variable

Tags: node.js

```
let api = {}
const axios = require('axios');
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/make_json/', {
    api:{"code":200}
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    api = response.data
    console.log(response.data)
  })
```

here i am fetching some data from different url in nodejs.
but it is coming response in the console.log()
but when i am adding the response to "api" variable it is not affecting that.
showing the same blank object for api.

Please have a look into my code..

Comment: From the code you have, we cannot know that the `api` var is empty. Where are you trying to access it afterwards? How do you know it's empty?

Comment: If you are assigning like this `api = response.data`, unless that property has a data property inside it, it will print undefined, try printing just `console.log(api)` and see what you got in there.

Comment: ya but , how can i assign api data to a variable..

Comment: If what you want is that your api has a property called data, just do `api.data = response.data` or `api = response` instead of `api = response.data`

Comment: still not working..